# Reducing template clutter in a class

Tags: c++

I'm sure this has been asked, but I couldn't find it. Suppose we have a simple template struct/class,

```
 template <class T>
 struct Point { 
     T x, y;        
 };
```

and another struct/class which uses this object,

```
typedef Point<double> point;          // Is this reasonable??
class UsesPointButOnlyOnFixedType {
    template <class T> 
    void UsePoint1(const Point<T>& p); // Annoying if this class is agnostic to the type
    void UsePoint2(const point& p); // Deceiving 
};
```

Except, the `UsesPointButOnlyOnFixedType` class only ever works with a single `Point` type (e.g. `double`). It is then senseless to require the type definitions for ever use of the `Point` struct in the `UsesPointButOnlyOnFixedType` class. Is there a standard practice for this situation? For instance, is there any problem with using a `typedef` as in the above example?

Comment: Is `UsesPointButOnlyOnFixedType` supposed to only ever work with `double` or should the user be able to choose *which* type `T` should be (but consistently across the members of the class)? And are you just bothered by typing `Point<double>` each time or are you bothered by the template parameter lists `template<class T>`, because these are kind of different issues.

Comment: Only `Point` should allow for the user to choose which type. `UsesPointButOnlyOnFixedType` only ever works with `double`, yes. 
I don't feel i should have to type `Point<anything>` if I only used a specific type for that class, exclusively. If writing from scratch its ok, but I have a few semi-large classes for which a lot needs to change including putting the definitions into the header files...

Comment: Then you can just use `Point<double>` everywhere and whether or not you typedef that is a matter of style choice mostly. I would at least use a more descriptive name though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, as you say in your comments, `UsesPointButOnlyOnFixedType` is supposed to work only with `Point<double>`, then you should *not* use

```
template <class T> 
void UsePoint1(const Point<T>& p);
```

because that would allow the function to be called with `Point<...>` arguments of any type.

Instead you should use

```
void UsePoint1(const Point<double>& p);
```

which you can of course typedef to avoid repeating the template argument, but I would put the type alias inside the class in that case, because it isn't really required to be visible outside of it:

```
class UsesPointButOnlyOnFixedType {
    using PointT = Point<double>;

    void UsePoint1(const PointT& p);
    void UsePoint2(const PointT& p); 
};
```